# Install Gunicorn in RH6 pointing to Python2.7

Tags: python, gunicorn

I am running a RHEL 6, with Python2.6 and Python2.7 in it.
I am trying to install Gunicorn, but when i install using rpm it is using Python2.6.
I would like to point it to Python2.7 which is in /usr/local/bin. I downloaded the gunicorn-19.1.0.tar.gz and did python2.7 setup.py install, but looks like it isn't creating any binary files to execute, can anyone help me how to install gunicorn without using pip and pointing to use specific version of python.
really appreciate the help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the best practices here.

For having a deployment, you shall have an isolated environment which could be either using Virtual Environments or Docker.

- **Using Virtual Environments**

Once you create a virtual environment, the installation will be easy.

virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/venvs/webapp

```
$ mkdir ~/venvs/
$ virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/venvs/webapp
$ source ~/venvs/webapp/bin/activate
$ pip install gunicorn
$ deactivate
```

- **Using Docker**

`

```
FROM python:2.7-slim

RUN pip install gunicorn json-logging-py

COPY logging.conf /logging.conf
COPY gunicorn.conf /gunicorn.conf

COPY myapp.py /

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "--config", "/gunicorn.conf", "--log-config", "/logging.conf", "-b", ":8000", "myapp:app"]
```

`

For more details :

- http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html
- https://sebest.github.io/post/protips-using-gunicorn-inside-a-docker-image/